Placing an atom along the line of the dipole moment of another molecule in ASE/GPAW
I have a solvent molecule, ethylene carbonate (EC), that I have calculated the dipole moment of. I want to place a Na atom at an appropriate distance from EC along the line of the dipole moment (in the opposite direction of the dipole vector).
Intuitively, that would be close to the carbonyl oxygen, but I want to automate this process for high-throughput calculations, for different solvent molecules.
My initial idea was to calculate the coordinate of the center of mass of EC, then place the Na atom a step in the opposite direction of the dipole moment (step length maybe 0.5 Å). On each step I calculate the distance between Na and all other atoms. When all the distances are above a certain value, maybe 2.5 Å, then I have my initial configuration.
My question is, before I endeavour on this solution, is there a simpler way?

It seems to me you simply want to place some molecule/atom at some fixed distance from the closest atom along a given direction?
If the above is correctly understood I would do this instead:

Normalize the dipole vector
d /= (d ** 2).sum() ** 0.5


Project the molecules atoms onto the normalized vector
proj_xyz = xyz @ d


Find the lowest/highest coordinate and calculate the offset that you wish to add
added_position = (proj_xyz.min() - 2.5) * d



Untested, but I think this should give you the displacement you want.

Quite elegant, it rids the iteration, thanks. Can I ask a follow-up question? I also want to place an anion molecule, in this case hexafluorophosphate (PF6-), at an appropriate distance from the solvent molecule in the direction of the dipole moment of the solvent.
PF6- is symmetric, so I don't have to think too much about the rotation of the anion. Thinking about it, I can probably also project the atoms of the anion onto the line of the dipole vector, then calculate the offset from the maximum coordinate of the solvent atoms and minimum of the anion's. This might work!

Yes, same procedure. ;)

If it helps, please mark the answer as the answer ;)
